# Load rails app config from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, configuration

I'd like to load some config settings from the database when my Rails (3.2.13) app starts:

```
class MyApp < Rails::Application
  #...normal config here...

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings         = {
    :address              => SystemSetting.system_smtp_host,
    :port                 => SystemSetting.system_smtp_port,
    :user_name            => SystemSetting.system_smtp_username,
    :password             => SystemSetting.system_smtp_password,
    :authentication       => SystemSetting.system_smtp_authentication,
    :enable_starttls_auto => SystemSetting.system_smtp_enable_starttls_auto }
end
```

But it appears that the database config has not been read at this point. I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

How can I accomplish this? Either make Rails initialize the database config first, or ... something else?

Comment: You might want to pause and consider using environment variables instead of values from the database. I've been down both roads and highly prefer the environment variables. Development environments that are setup this way are greatly aided by the dotenv gem: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: Possibly, but this is more of a CMS and I figured having the configuration all editable and in one location would simplify things in the end. I will take a look at your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding practices: Doing stuff like this can be problematic because your application relies on your database to be full when in fact it should support an empty database. Two examples that I can think of are when you try to create a database from scratch (e.g. rake db:setup), or in tests environments.

However, if have no other choice: I would move the mailer initialization to your system_setting.rb or an initializer (where you are guaranteed to have a connection).

**config/initializers/load_system_settings.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp
MyApp::Application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings         = {
  :address              => SystemSetting.system_smtp_host,
  :port                 => SystemSetting.system_smtp_port,
  :user_name            => SystemSetting.system_smtp_username,
  :password             => SystemSetting.system_smtp_password,
  :authentication       => SystemSetting.system_smtp_authentication,
  :enable_starttls_auto => SystemSetting.system_smtp_enable_starttls_auto
}
```

Comment: In this case, "system settings" are not required. These values can be empty at first, and filled in later on.

I think it's a good idea to initialize somewhere else, as you mentioned. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example initializer with my SMTP config pulled into it? I think it has to be in the context of my Application class, right?

Answer (score 0):

Manually connect and load values from database.

```
class Application < Rails::Application

  # Set your app path
  app_base = 'MY_APPLICATION_PATH' 

  # Load db configs
  db_yml = YAML.load_file("#{app_base}/config/database.yml")["production"]

  # Establish db connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter=>db_yml['adapter'], :database=>db_yml['database'], :username=>db_yml['username'], :password=>db_yml['password']) 

  # load model if not 
  require "#{app_base}/app/model/system_setting.rb" unless defined?('SystemSetting')

  #...normal config here...

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors           = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method                 = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings                   = {
    :address                                          => SystemSetting.system_smtp_host,
    :port                                             => SystemSetting.system_smtp_port,
    :user_name                                        => SystemSetting.system_smtp_username,
    :password                                         => SystemSetting.system_smtp_password,
    :authentication                                   => SystemSetting.system_smtp_authentication,
    :enable_starttls_auto                             => SystemSetting.system_smtp_enable_starttls_auto }

  #close sql connection after loaded 
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this a "bad idea"? :)